# How to format date of unix timestamp from an object into Handlebars.js template?

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp, handlebars.js

I have unix timestamps as a value in the objects of my context for my Handlebars.js template. I need the timestamp to be formatted as m/d/yyyy on my page. I've been searching for hours but I'm not even sure how to implement some of the solutions I've found.

Here's an example of what I'm working with:

My Handlebars context:

```
var comments = [
    {name: 'kris', comment: 'hi', timestamp: 69379200000},
    {name: 'chase', comment: 'bye', timestamp: 1007683200000},
    {name: 'peter', comment: 'hello', timestamp: 69379200000}
];
```

In my Handlebars template, I need {{timestamp}} to display a date such as 2/14/2015. Help!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using `moment.js`.

To convert UNIX timestamp to your format:

```
moment(unixTimeStamp).format('M/D/YYYY')
```

To use `moment.js` in the browser:

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
```

[ref](http://momentjs.com/docs/)